# "Display information for each person"

Tags: ruby

I can't get the code to display the information about the people correctly. I'm able to list the names but not the ages.

```
my_group = ["person_1", "person_2", "person_3"]
person_1 = {name: "erik", gender: "male", age: 26}
person_2 = {name: "erika", gender: "female", age: 26}
person_3 = {name: "erka", gender: "alpha", age: 27}

my_group.each do |name|
  my_group.each do |age|
    puts "Hello, #{name} is about #{age} years old"
  end

  puts "Hello, #{name} is about #{age} years old"
end
```

I don't get an error code, but it does not list the age with the names.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually your `my_group` contains only `Strings`. If you want to include **persons variable** you may include them as **variables** (without `""`):

```
person_1 = {name: "erik", gender: "male", age: 26}
person_2 = {name: "erika", gender: "female", age: 26}
person_3 = {name: "erka", gender: "alpha", age: 27}

my_group = [ person_1, person_2, person_3 ]
```

Then you can use [`Array#each`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Array.html#method-i-each) method to loop on each **person** into this array.

```
my_group.each do |person|
     puts "Hello, #{person[:name]} is about #{person[:age]} years old"
end
```

Also note that each person is a [`Hash`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Hash.html). If you want to access to age property of `person_1`, for example, you have to do this:

```
puts person_1[:name]
```

Comment: Yepp, I understand now. Thank you so much for taking the time to help me!